# VisualForce Email template: how to disable the Link from the outputField (of type reference)

Tags: visualforce, email-template

Is there anyway to disable the link from the apex:outputField when using it in an email template?

Code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedto.RTS_Items__r}" var="o">

<b>Product Code:</b>&nbsp;

                    <apex:outputField value="{!o.SKU__c}"/><br/>

<b>Description:</b>&nbsp;
     <apex:outputField value="{!o.Item__c}"/><br/>
```

O.item is of type 'reference' and on the email it displays the item name but also creates it as a link to the item itself. I cannot just get the name unless I go through another lookup and I would like to avoid that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<apex:outputField>` to an `<apex:outputText>`, and the email shouldn't populate the link.  However, the link will not be displayed on the Page also.  You could always re-populate the link pretty easily with **jQuery** on the VF page if need be.

(On a page I use externally in a Site, I used `<apex:detail>` to easily show the Page Detail for a record (without the work or re-creating a custom VF layout), but I had to remove all those links from lookup fields (cause the links didn't work in the Site context).  And it wasn't too difficult once I got familiar with **jQuery**)

---

**Update:**

Lookup Fields are a special sort in Salesforce.  When you reference one in a `apex:outputField` on a VF page (like your example `<apex:outputField value="{!o.Item__c}"/>`), the VF page display's `o.Item__r.Name` but with a link to the record (of the form `'/o.Item__c'`).   Since you only need the name and not the link, just pull the name:

Ex.   `<apex:outputField value="{!o.Item__r.Name}"/>`

**Be sure to query this field first in your controller!**

Comment: Thanks for your help Amator, when changing it to OutputText it only gives me the reference and not the description. I am looking for just the description without the hyperlink.

Comment: try this:  `<apex:outputField value="{!o.Item__r.Name}"/>`   You'll need to make sure the field `Item__r.Name" is queried before you can use it on the VF page.